# Tkinter: Access canvas from button handler

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I update the canvas from a function called by a button? Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ImageTk

tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, bg="white", width=300, height=200)
canvas.grid()

def displayLabel():
    photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="Logo.png")
    canvas.create_image(0,0, image=photoimage, anchor = NW)

b3 = Button(tk, text="Display Label", width=30, command= displayLabel())
b3.grid(row=1)

tk.mainloop()
```

Pressing the "Display Label" button does nothing. I've tried designating the canvas global in the method, or passing the canvas in as an argument (using `command = lambda (displayLabel(canvas))`, both to no effect. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I now realize my question is a [duplicate of this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576843/is-there-a-known-win32-tkinter-bug-with-respect-to-displaying-photos-on-a-canvas?), but @shalitmaan's answer helped me in ways the other one didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a `PhotoImage` or other Image object to a Tkinter widget, you must keep your own reference to the image object. If you don’t, the image won’t always show up.
Here is essentially what I'm trying to say:

```
def displayLabel():
    photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="lena.png")
    canvas.create_image(0,0, image=photoimage, anchor = NW)
    canvas.image=photoimage #keep the reference!
```

I learned it from [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-do-my-tkinter-images-not-appear.htm).

**Also** you need to remove the parenthesis `()`

```
b3 = Button(tk, text="Display Label", width=30, command= displayLabel) #no parenthesis
```

otherwise it will be called directly without even the button press. You might not have noticed it up until now since `Tk` was just making the image blank as you may understand now from the link.

**Also** if you want to send some arguments to `displayLabel` you need to use `lambda`. For eg:

```
b3 = Button(tk, text="Display Label", width=30, command= lambda:displayLabel(args))
```

In your asked question,you were missing the colon `:`

Comment: Only one line is need to create the tk image and save the reference. `canvas.image = ImageTk....` and then use `canvas.image` in the `create_image` call.  Adding parentheses back to `displayLabel`, to pass args (after you correctly said to remove them) is wrong.