# empty Tkinter window appears in place of image

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load images dynamically through browse button to Tkinter window but I am getting the empty window. This is the code of callback function of browse button

```
supformats = [
('Windows Bitmap','*.bmp'),
('Portable Network Graphics','*.png'),
('JPEG ','*.jpg'),
('CompuServer GIF','*.gif'),
]
filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=supformats)
FILENAME = filename
im=Image.open(FILENAME)
w=im.size[0]
h=im.size[1]
root = Tkinter.Tk()
#canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h)
#canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
#tk_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = FILENAME)
#canvas.create_image(image=tk_img)
im.show()
root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for everyone who will help

Comment: you might wanna refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22369189/2276527)

Answer (score 0):

From effbot's explanation http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm  Note that the file is accessed once only, not twice.  This assumes you are using the Python Imaging Library in Tkinter as you did not state what image toolkit is being used.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

You can use a PhotoImage instance everywhere Tkinter accepts an image object.
An example:
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```